# How do I fix "repair device" in android studio avd manager?

Tags: android

I installed android studio 1.5.1. Running windows 10 on an AMD, so no hardware acceleration on the emulation.  Googling it, I find I can use ARM instead of x86 emulation.  But whenever I try to add a device using it, the Actions column shows "repair device".  If I click View Details, nothing happens. There is an image showing that there's some kind of error (yield sign with !) but I can't seem to do anything with it to see the error. Double clicking on it just opens it in edit mode but gives me no information about what's wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you try for other emulators like Genymotion or BlueStack or even if you google for android emulators you can find so many options!!!

Comment: Because I understand Genymotion has the same problem with hardware acceleration.  Also, I can probably try a dozen different emulators and each one will probably have something wrong with them.  How about just trying to answer the question instead?

Comment: As per the documentation: `AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) extensions (only supported for Linux)` [check it once](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm). You can read more on it here. Hope it'll be help full for you.

Comment: I appreciate it, but like I said, I am running windows, not linux.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in 2022! I solved it by clicking the edit button on the emulator device and changing the emulated hardware(phone) to something else. It refreshed and the error sign left.
Do close the running emulator before doing this though. If the error persists, you may want to remove the particular AVD and get a different one.